# Computing FundamentalFrequency

Tags: sound, signal-processing, wavelet-analysis

How does *Mathematica* use [`AudioLocalMeasurements`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AudioLocalMeasurements.html) to compute the *fundamental frequency*?
Is there any formula? I can't seem to find what method *Mathematica* makes use of.

[Here](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/computational-audio/fundamental-frequency-detection.html?product=mathematica) is an example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Cepstrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cepstrum),Wiki says

> It was originally invented for characterizing the seismic echoes resulting from earthquakes and bomb explosions. It has also been used to determine the fundamental frequency of human speech and to analyze radar signal returns.

In `CepstrumArray`:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think this deserves an upvote for "quefrency" alone.

Comment: @partida Where is the calculation for the variable "peaks"?  As is, the code does not work.  Please fix.

Comment: @Steve Sure I added it

Comment: @partida  Thank you very much.  I really appreciate it!  :-)